# Programming average with arrays

Tags: java

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    //10 name arrays
    String players[]=new String[10];
    players[0]="Kevin Love";
    players[1]="Kyrie Irving";
    players[2]="Lebron James";
    players[3]="Dion Waiters";
    players[4]="Shawn Marion";
    players[5]="Tristan Thompson";
    players[6]="Anderson Varejo";
    players[7]="Joe Harris";
    players[8]= "Mike Miller";
    players[9]="Brendan Haywood";
    //10 height arrays in centimeter
    double heights[]= new double [10];
    heights[0]=208;
    heights[1]=191;
    heights[2]=203;
    heights[3]=193;
    heights[4]=201;
    heights[5]=206;
    heights[6]=208;
    heights[7]=198;
    heights[8]=203;
    heights[9]=213;
    System.out.println("The average of the players height is: " + calcAverage(heights)+ " cm");
}
// for calculating average for the players height
public static double calcAverage(double[] heights) { 
    double sum = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i < heights.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + heights[i]; 
    } 
    double average = sum / (double)heights.length;
    return average; 
}
// comparing height with the average
public static void heightvsAverage(String [] players,  double [] heights, double average)
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        while (heights[i]>average)
        {
            System.out.println("Players with above average are:");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Players|Heights");
            System.out.println("---------+---------");
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            System.out.println(String.format("%-11s|%8s", players[i],df.format(heights[i])));
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am having a problem with the third method i am trying to compare the heights with the average, and i am trying to make a table in the third method that outputs players with height above average. Main method and method 2 are excellent it's just that i am having difficulty making the chart in method 3

Comment: what is current output ? and what output do you want ?

Comment: Atul Nar, the current output is the average and i want the output to be the average and the table of players that have their height above average(using void in method 3)

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1)  What is going on here?

```
     while (heights[i]>average)
```

Think about it!

2)  How many headers does a table need?  How many times is your code printing the table header?  Why?

Comment: Well think harder.  Why are you using `while` there???

Comment: idk before i had if (heights[i]>average) { blah blah blach}

Comment: i think i shouldn't use while because it doesn't really make sense saying if height is greater than the average, cuz height can be same as average too or smaller than average too

Comment: @KulwinderBatth I think you miss understood what `while` dose. Try breaking at the `while` and debug the code in steps.

Comment: @KulwinderBatth btw you answered your own question in your comment, you said it yourself "if height is greater than the average" not "while height is greater than the average".

Comment: @DimaMaligin, yea i changed it to if however still not working

Comment: @KulwinderBatth what exactly is not working?

Comment: the table is not working and i don't wanna call it in the main method

Comment: @KulwinderBatth The table is not working is ambiguous be more specific. Take your time and edit the question so we can stop spamming this answer.

Comment: @DimaMaligin, for the third method i am trying to make a chart or a table basically for that chart or table i wanna have players with above average height be printed in the chart. Idk how to do that, that's why i am trying to do if height[i]>average.

Comment: @KulwinderBatth edit your question to let us know what exactly is it you are having problems with. This is my last comment in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use if in place of while in third method

Comment: Atul Nar it doesn't work if i change while to if, doesn't dispplay

Comment: i am getting following output when i change while to if please check if that is your required answer :
The average of the players height is: 202.4 cm
Players with above average are:
Players|Heights
---------+---------
Kevin Love |208
Players with above average are:
Players|Heights
---------+---------
Lebron James|203
Players with above average are:
Players|Heights
---------+---------
Tristan Thompson|206
Players with above average are:
Players|Heights
---------+---------
Anderson Varejo|208
Players with above average are:
Players|Heights
---------+---------
Mike Miller|203

Comment: sorry one more thing  heightvsAverage(players,heights,calcAverage(heights));
you didnt call the third method so call in in your main method

Comment: yes that's it what i want if u don't mind can u please post the third code

Comment: do i have to call it in main method, i was trying to avoid putting everything in main method

Comment: first tell me will it work ! and next thing is you write code for comparing and showing result in method so how can you expect to see it as output without calling the method !!!

Comment: u are right but u can still compare them without putting in main metod, my teacher showed us an example i can't remember

Comment: also for the chart i don't want it to say Player with abvoe average are: for each person

Comment: ok i got it but can u help me with the table like make it look proper, idk why the table is not working that's why i put System.out.println(String.format("%-11s|%8s", players[i],df.format(heights[i])));

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're never calling the method, so I've added the function call after you display the average

```
heights[9]=213;
    System.out.println("The average of the players height is: " + calcAverage(heights)+ " cm");
    //Add this line 
    heightvsAverage(players, heights, calcAverage(heights));
```

Make sure you remove the while back to the if, otherwise you'll have an infinite loop.
Finally, check what the other answers told you, you should only be displaying your header once, then the player's names.

**EDIT**

I changed the function to this:

```
    // comparing height with the average
public static void heightvsAverage(String [] players,  double [] heights, double average)
{
    System.out.println("Players with above average are:\n");
    System.out.println("Players|Heights");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if (heights[i]>average)
        {
            System.out.println("---------+---------");
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            System.out.println(String.format("%-11s|%8s", players[i],df.format(heights[i])));
        }
    }
}
```

that and adding the function call that I mentioned before will get you the print that I'm guessing you need.
FYI, this is simple analysis, and I would think many would agree you gotta try a bit harder yourself before asking others to solve the problem for you, otherwise you won't learn much.

Good luck!

Comment: Maor ok thans and also can u help me with making the chart look proper?